# How to consume json response in jQuery each

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ui

I try to append a country list in in html. there is a country name with id in my JSON response data. Please see my below image.

[image]

Here the 15 is country id and Brazil is country name. But I am clueless how to iterate the response array in `$.each`.

Comment: is response in array or string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [JQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) you can iterate in your json with .each method:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/myfile.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + val[0] + "'>" + val[1] + "</li>" );
  });
  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "countries",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Otherwise, if you have a string:

```
 var jsonData = [["15","Brazil"],["14","Italy"]];
 $.each(jsonData, function(key,val){
    $('#divID').append('<div>id:'+ val[0] + ', country:' + val[1] + '</div>');
 })
```

Here [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TPLU6/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var arr = [["15","Brazil"],["14","Italy"],["13","Spain"],["15","Scotland"]];

$.each(arr, function(key,obj){
    // obj contains array like : ["15","Brazil"]
    $('body').append('<div>id:'+obj[0]+', country:' + obj[1]+'</div>');
 })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bSfT2/1/